# Basic Angular Material table is showing test data, but not my data

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

The table is showing the data it's supposed to when using a test object array, but not when using the actual object array that I need in the table, and I can't figure out what I'm missing!

This is the test array:

```
export interface TestData {
  compa: string;
  company: string;
}

const TEST_DATA: TestData[] = [
  {compa: 'blah', company: 'blahblahblah'},
  {compa: 'blah2', company: 's'},
  {compa: 'blah23', company: 's'},
  {compa: 'blah234', company: 's'},
  {compa: 'blah2345', company: 'fads'}
];
```

```
displayedColumns = ['company'];
dataSource = TEST_DATA;
```

... and when trying to display only the company, it is successful

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Company </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let site"> {{ site.company }} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

The 'sites' array is retrieved from a database and it's value is set OnInit:

```
sites: Site[] = [];
```

But this doesn't work:

```
displayedColumns = ['company'];
dataSource = this.sites;
```

... even though this.sites is also an object array with each object containing a field with the key 'company', just like the TEST_DATA array.
I can even `console.log(this.sites)` and it returns the array, but when I set `dataSource = this.sites`, and then try to `console.log(this.dataSource)` it's empty...
This is the code that gets data from back-end

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sitesService.getUtilitySites('Evansville');
    this.sitesSub = this.sitesService
      .getSiteUpdatedListener()
      .subscribe((siteData: {sites: Site[]}) => {
        this.sites = siteData.sites;
        this.sitesLoaded = true;
      });
    }
```

I'm baffled... please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it in NgOninit function

```
ngOnInit() {
this.sitesService.getUtilitySites('Evansville');
this.sitesSub = this.sitesService
  .getSiteUpdatedListener()
  .subscribe((siteData: {sites: Site[]}) => {
    this.sites = siteData.sites;
    this.dataSource = siteData.sites;
    this.sitesLoaded = true;
  });
}
```

and where is the code that it is getting from backend? if your subscribing make sure this code is in the subscribe

Comment: Tried this :( 

I tried
`dataSource;`
Then:
`ngOnInit() {this.dataSource = this.sites}`

Still is empty

Comment: where is the code in the ts file that gets the data from the backend

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: add this to the subscribe       this.dataSource = siteData.sites; i updated the answer

Comment: this worked.. I could have sworn I tried it. I must have done it outside the subscription.

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning to **this.dataSource** instead of just dataSource ie. replace `dataSource = this.sites` with `this.dataSource = this.sites`

Comment: `dataSource = this.sites` is the first time I set dataSource, so I wouldn't be able to do `this.dataSource = this.sites` because dataSource wouldn't exist yet

Comment: You should only declare the variable there. The assignment should be done inside a function or a lifecycle hook like ngOnInit to get the desired result as demonstrated in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try -ChangeDetectorRef , some times angular will is not taking refreshed data,

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef  } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cd : ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

where backend data binding to datasource add cd.detectChanges like this,

```
displayedColumns = ['company'];
dataSource = this.sites;
this.cd.detectChanges();
```